# Setting noatime via mount options vs no atime updates (A) file attribute

Tags: linux, ext4, btrfs, xfs, noatime

From `man chattr`

> When a file with the 'A' attribute set is accessed, its atime record
>   is not modified.  This avoids a certain amount of disk I/O for laptop
>   systems.

However when I am remounting a filesystem with the `noatime` mount option:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -o remount,noatime /dev/sdb1 /newfs/
```

creating a file in it

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd /newfs/
[root@localhost newfs]# touch myfile
```

and getting its file attributes:

```
[root@localhost newfs]# lsattr myfile 
-------------e-- myfile
```

the `A` file attribute is not set despite the fact.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: `lsattr(1)` does not list the [extended attributes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html) and `chattr(1)` does not change them. Both commands are working with the  *file attributes* which are extra inode flags supported by some filesystems with like ext4, btrfs or xfs. The two are completely unrelated and independent. Extended attributes are notably used to implement file capabilities(7), selinux (`security.selinux`) and ACLs (`system.posix_acl_access`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected: the two behaviours are orthogonal. Setting the `A` attribute on a file ensures that its access time is never updated, irrespective of mount options. Mounting a file system with `noatime` ensures that no access time is updated on it, irrespective of file attributes.

Mounting a file system with a given set of options doesn’t affect any related attributes on files created while the options are active; thus files created with `noatime` active don’t have the `A` attribute automatically set, just like it’s possible to create device nodes on a file system mounted with `nodev`, or executables on a file system mounted with `noexec`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behaviour.

Either of them will prevent the atime being updated, but they are independent.

The kernel has no system call to query the overall status.  You have to check both of them yourself.

Comment: but yield the exact same end result I assume?

Comment: Yes, the end result is the same.